# Is this necessary to pay to upload my app in android market?

Tags: android, google-play

Since i am new to android market, is it necessary to pay $25 in android market to upload my one app?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: yes, it is. Google introduced this to avoid pure spamming submissions.

Comment: is there any other way that my app is visible on internet without registration to market?

Comment: @tigmanshu it is possible to distribute by any means, but users will have to have third party installs enabled on their device(most likely)

Answer (score 1):

Yes in order to have stuff on the market you need to pay that fee.

This helps keep multiples upon multiples of Hello Worlds off the market :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the market, you have to pay the fee.  It's only a one time fee, unlike the iOS app store which is a yearly subscription.